# Parsley: personalizar mensagem de erro

Tags: javascript, parsley

Estou usando o plugin [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) para validação de formulários e estou criando alguns métodos de validação adicionais, entretanto, estou com dificuldade com a personalização das mensagens de erro dessas funções.

De acordo com a documentação do site, podemos adicionar um método customizado da seguinte forma:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('equals', {
    validateString: function validateString(value, comparar_com, texto_erro) {
        return (value === comparar_com);
    },
    requirementType: 'string',
    messages: {
        pt_BR: 'O seguinte valor é esperado: %s'
    }
});
```

Com o código acima o Parsley exibiria na mensagem de erro o segundo parâmetro da função, que seria o 'comparar_com', mas eu queria que o texto definido no terceiro parâmetro, 'texto_erro', fosse exibido na mensagem de erro, e não o 'comparar_com'.

Alguém sabe me dizer se isso é possível? O Parsley utiliza a seguinte função para montar as mensagens de erro:

```
// Kind of light `sprintf()` implementation
formatMessage: function formatMessage(string, parameters) {
...
```

Estou tentando alguma coisa aqui, ainda sem sucesso, mas será que estou no caminho certo?

Comment: Ontem olhando alguns links na internet percebi o seguinte, a função validaeString (ou qualquer outra variação) recebe até três parâmetros: `value, requirement e fieldInstance`. Ou seja, do jeito que estava imaginando já não dá... =(

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para deixar registrado como personalizar uma mensagem de erro utilizando um dos parâmetros usados na validação como parte da mensagem, vejam abaixo um exemplo de uma função que adicionei ao Parsley:

```
/**
 * Verifica se o valor existe em uma lista de valores permitidos
 *
 * @param   string    value   Valor que será validado
 * @param   mix       list    Lista de valores permitidos. Pode ser um array ou uma string separada por vírgula
 * 
 * @return  bool
 *
 * Utilização:
 * data-parsley-in-list="Opção 1,Opção 2"
 *
 */
window.Parsley.addValidator('inList',
{
    validateString: function validateString(value, list)
    {
        if(typeof list != 'object')
        {
            list = list.split(',');
        }
        if(list.length > 0)
        {
            for(var i in list)
            {
                // trim
                if(value === list[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, ''))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Monta a string com a lista das opções
        var new_list = list.join(', ');

        // Redefine a mensagem de erro formatando a lista de opções
        var new_error_msg = 'O valor deve ser uma das seguintes opções: ' + new_list;

        // Atualiza a mensagem do erro
        window.Parsley._validatorRegistry.catalog.pt_BR.inList = new_error_msg;

        return false;
    },
    requirementType: 'string',
    messages:
    {
        pt_BR: 'O valor deve ser uma das seguintes opções: %s'
    }
});
```